# Slight translation with coordinate-transformation from Gauss-Kruger to WGS 84. Possible Reasons?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, coordinate-system, proj

I have a number of points in Gauss-Kruger, Zone 3 that I want to convert to display them within Google-Earth. Assuming WGS84 for Google-Earth the transformed coordinated differ from the original ones about 140m to the north-east.

I am doing the coordinate transformation using the "PROJ.4 - Cartographic Projections Library" (http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) with the following proj4 strings:

**Gauß Krüger, Zone 3:**

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1.000000 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs
```

**WGS84:**

```
 +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs - "
```

Could somebody check if my proj4 strings are correct (especially WGS84 for Google Earth) or suggest other causes of the error?

Answer (score 6):

Your Gauss-Krueger projection uses `+datum=potsdam`. Up to 2012, this was hard coded in proj4 to a very unprecise value using a 3-parameter-transformation.

You find more exact values for 7-parameter transformations in this topic:

http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=12723

There is an even better ntv2-grid transformation available [here (take the binary)](http://crs.bkg.bund.de/crseu/crs/descrtrans/BeTA/de_dhdn2etrs_beta.php), that has to be in the same folder as your application and data, unlsss you specify full pathnames.

To compare the different possible values, I made this test batch file:

```
echo epsg31467-epsg4326 >out.txt
cs2cs +init=epsg:31467 +to +init=epsg:4326 31467.txt >>out.txt

echo proj-Definition epsg >>out.txt
cs2cs +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs  +to +init=epsg:4326 31467.txt >>out.txt

echo proj-definition Qgis >>out.txt
cs2cs +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=582,105,414,1.04,0.35,-3.08,8.3 +units=m +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326 31467.txt >>out.txt

echo proj-definition nadgrid >>out.txt
cs2cs +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +k=1.000000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +nadgrids=./BETA2007.gsb +wktext +to +init=epsg:4326 31467.txt >>out.txt

echo epsg31467-epsg3785 >>out.txt
cs2cs +init=epsg:31467 +to +init=epsg:3785 31467.txt >>out.txt
echo proj-definition Qgis >>out.txt
cs2cs +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=582,105,414,1.04,0.35,-3.08,8.3 +units=m +no_defs +to +init=epsg:3785 31467.txt >>out.txt

echo proj-definition nadgrid >>out.txt
cs2cs +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +k=1.000000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +nadgrids=./BETA2007.gsb +wktext +to +init=epsg:3785 31467.txt >>out.txt

echo epsg31467-epsg3857 >>out.txt
cs2cs +init=epsg:31467 +to +init=epsg:3857 31467.txt >>out.txt
echo proj-definition Qgis >>out.txt
cs2cs +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=582,105,414,1.04,0.35,-3.08,8.3 +units=m +no_defs +to +init=epsg:3857 31467.txt >>out.txt

echo epsg31467-epsg900913 >>out.txt
cs2cs +init=epsg:31467 +to +init=epsg:900913 31467.txt >>out.txt
echo epsg31467-proj900913 >>out.txt
cs2cs +init=epsg:31467 +to +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +over +no_defs 31467.txt >>out.txt
echo proj31467-proj900913 >>out.txt
cs2cs +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=582,105,414,1.04,0.35,-3.08,8.3 +units=m +no_defs +to +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +over +no_defs 31467.txt >>out.txt
```

with any sample Gauss-Krüger lon-lat coordinate pair in 31467.txt

Comment: thank you. Do you think the issue occurs with the latest proj4 version also? I am using proj4 with cs2cs and just installed that a week ago.

Comment: It depends on the software you use. Latest builds from gisinternals are up-to-date, while FWtools and proj4js may be a bit behind. I always prefer to use the full `+towgs84` parameters.

Comment: ok. As I am not too familiar with proj4, could you tell me how to modify my proj4 strings having found `potsdam "towgs84=597.1,71.4,412.1,0.894,0.068,-1.563,7.58" "Germany (West - South - 47d00N to 50d20'N)" "Accuracy <1m"` in the thread you linked to?

Comment: Thank you for your effort! However when running your script on the inputfile containing `456433.163000 5430249.143000 126.410000` I am getting the following errors: `Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012
<cs2cs>: while processing file: 31467.txt, line 1
pj_transform(): failed to load datum shift file
Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012
<cs2cs>: while processing file: 31467.txt, line 1
pj_transform(): failed to load datum shift file
Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012
<cs2cs>: 
projection initialization failure
cause: no options found in 'init' file
program abnormally terminated`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18375/discussion-between-siwica-and-andrej).

Comment: I added the download link for the NTv2 grid Beta2007.gsb. You might provide full path names if it is not found by default.