# Openlayers(with proj4.js) transforms coordinates incorrectly

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, proj4js

I encountered a strange behaviour in Openlayers(2) while transforming a point from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:31467.

The Input lat/lon in EPSG 4326 is:
48.002718, 7.841573

This is the output in Openlayers:

OpenLayers with latest proj4.js:
EPSG 31467: 3413629.117584194 5318941.910572025

https://jsfiddle.net/cag5n970/4/

OpenLayers with proj4.js 1.1.0:
EPSG 31467: 3413629.117584194 5318941.910572027

https://jsfiddle.net/cpwqA/75/

This is the output of epsg.io:

[image]

With different desktop-GIS-systems I also get the correct coordinates:

**GlobalMapper:** EPSG 31467: 3413632.71674 5318940.01018

**FME:** EPSG 31467: 3413632.7176193688 5318940.0085047819

**ArcGIS:** EPSG31467: 3413633,330872 5318935,858400

**OpenJump:** EPSG31467: 3413633.0419754055 5318938.324243281

**QGIS:** EPSG31467: 3413633.35 5318938.35

Here you can see the shift of up to 7.5 meters between the transformed OpenLayers coordinate and the result of the other transformations:

[image]

Any idea why Openlayers or the used proj4.js has a wrong output of the transformation?

Comment: Is one or other transform omitting the datum transformation from WGS84 spheroid to Bessel 1841?  `cs2cs` gives me `3413633.36      5318938.36`, but if I tell it to assume that the inputs are already on the Bessel spheroid, I get `3413567.63      5318836.81` instead.  Mind you, that's a distance of 139 metres, which is rather larger than the error you are seeing.

Comment: I think it's likely that the software packages are using different transformations. epsg.io, for 31467 is using EPSG::1777, DHDN to WGS 84 (2). I can't see how to reset the default transformation there, but didn't look very hard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120754/slight-translation-with-coordinate-transformation-from-gauss-kruger-to-wgs-84-p . The datum shift oft potsdam datum has been changed inside proj.4 in 2012. And if you want it **really** exact, you should take a datum shift grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a custom proj4.js definition for EPSG:31467.

I replaced "**+datum=potsdam**" with

"**+towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.70**" to achieve a 7 parameter Helmert Transformation instead of the used simple 3 parameter translation:

```
proj4.defs["EPSG:31467"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.70 +units=m +no_defs";

// instead of   
//proj4.defs["EPSG:31467"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs";
```

Now the transformation has the same output like QGIS:
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/wecsoo3x/1/

Comment: GDAL 2.2.0dev comes with this Proj.4 string `# DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 3
<31467> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs  <>` with no +ellps=bessel  and without +towgs84.

Comment: proj4.defs["EPSG:31467"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs"; does not lead to the "better" result

Comment: No better than what? The original one or the one you got with the +towgs84 fix?

Comment: @user30184 the result is the same as with the default OpenLayers transformation. It seems as if towgs84 is missing only a 3 parameter spatial translations is used

Comment: There seems to be mismatch between the epsg file that has been delivered with my GDAL installation and the parameters which are really used. Gdalsrsinfo http://www.gdal.org/gdalsrsinfo.html gives the same string that you have used `PROJ.4 : '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +
towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs '`

Comment: regarding possible values of potsdam datum shifts, see my answer at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120754/slight-translation-with-coordinate-transformation-from-gauss-kruger-to-wgs-84-p